# Tomcat JDBC Pool Metrics

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, connection, metrics, pool

I am running Tomcat 8.0.29 and I'm using the Tomcat provided JDBC Pool initialized using JNDI resource.  I am connecting to a Postgres database and am using the JDBC driver released with 9.4. Everything works fine and I am able to connect and execute queries.

I would like to gather metrics about the connection pool from within my java program.  For example, I would like to know how many idle connections I currently have and/or how many connections from the pool are in use. I have tried increasing the logging level and that did not give me any of these pool metrics.  I have tried looking at JMX and I do not see any MBeans that have this information.  I did see some other posts claiming that I could use MBeans, but the version that I am running doesn't have those MBeans.

I have searched quite a bit and cannot find an answer to this simple question.  I basically just want to log or be able to query metrics related to the JDBC pool within Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I do, but **I have it tested in Tomcat 7, but not yet in Tomcat 8**.

First you must gain access to `javax.sql.DataSource` object. It should not be difficult if you are able to execute SQL. Once you have the DataSource object reference, casting it to `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource` should let you obtain the metrics you are looking for:

```
public double testDsUsagePercentage(javax.sql.DataSource ds){
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource basic = (org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource)ds;
    int total = basic.getMaxActive();
    int idle = basic.getNumIdle();
    int active = basic.getNumActive();
    double percentage = this.calcUsagePercent(total, active + idle);
    return percentage;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param max
 * @param used
 * @return
 */
private double calcUsagePercent(int max, int used){
    if(max == 0){
        return 0.0;
    }
    return ((double)used / (double)max)*100;
}
```

Comment: I just attempted this in 8.  There is no org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource, but there is a package name to org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource. I used that instead and everything compiled properly, however, during runtime I received the following error "SEVERE: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource".  I ended up doing something different but it was more involved.  I will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this issue by creating a custom JDBCInterceptor. My interceptor was very simple:

```
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool;
    import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor;
    import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection;

    public class MetricsInterceptor extends JdbcInterceptor{
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss");
        @Override
        public void reset(ConnectionPool cPool, PooledConnection conn) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Connection Pool:Pool Size:"+cPool.getSize());
        System.out.println("Connection Pool:Active Count:"+cPool.getActive());
        System.out.println("Connection Pool:Idle Count:"+cPool.getIdle());
        System.out.println("Connection Pool:Wait Count:"+cPool.getWaitCount());
        System.out.println("Connection:ID:"+conn.toString());
        System.out.println("Connection:Last    Validated:"+sdf.format(conn.getLastValidated()));
        System.out.println("Connection:Last Connected:"+sdf.format(conn.getLastConnected()));
        System.out.println("Connection:is Released:"+conn.isReleased());
        System.out.println("Connection:is Suspect:"+conn.isSuspect());

    }

}
```

I exported this into a JAR and placed it in my tomcat/lib directory.  I also updated my context.xml JNDI datasource to include my new interceptor.

```
<Resource name="jdbc/postgres" auth="Container"
......jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;
              org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer; **org.mayan.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.MetricsInterceptor**"/>
```

When I restarted Tomcat, my console was printing out connection metrics that I was looking for.

Hope this helps someone else.